# Compare UIColor to Text Label/String

Tags: ios, swift, if-statement, colors

How can I test to see if the textColor of a label (meaningLabel) matches the name of the color in another label (textColorLabel)?

ex: 
(red color appears on screen) == "RED" (appears on label) --> score += 1 
(blue color appears on screen) == "BLUE" (appears on label) --> "boo -- no match"

Here is my attempt:

```
    func updateScore() {
        if meaningLabel.textColor == textColorLabel.textColor{
            print("yay -- match")
            score += 1
            scoreLabel.text = String(score)
        } else {
            print("boo -- no match")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a dictionary of text and UIColor and then use it for validation. Here is the example:

```
 var colorDict : [String:UIColor] = ["Red": UIColor.red,"Blue":UIColor.blue,"Black":UIColor.black]
 func updateScore() {

    if meaningLabel.textColor == colorDict[textColorLabel.text!] {
         print("yay -- match")
         score += 1
         scoreLabel.text = String(score)
     } else {
         print("boo -- no match")
     }
 }
```

> Note:- Make sure to use the Dictionary Key name as the text for your
>   textColorLabel

Comment: Can you explain more on your note to " use the Dictionary Key name as the text for your textColorLabel." Does that mean iterate through the dict to get the key values and then..? I tried implementing your suggestion and now my scoreLabel is not working 

Comment: No, what I mean is: Make sure your textColorLabel text matches the "Dictionary Keys". i.e. your textLabelColor can be = "Red" || "Blue" || "Black" . You understand?